# WhatsApp HTML Sharing Link for Image

Tags: html, whatsapp

I know you can share messages with and this is working on android and ios now:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello world this is a message and a link http://www.example.com/image.jpg">Share with whatsapp</a>
```

However I'd like to share an image trough a button on my website like someone would share an image from his phone (gallery). Is this anyhow possible?

Comment: As today (Sept 23 2015) there is no way to achieve this. The best approach is to share the link and serve it with some `force download` headers.. Quite invasive, but it's the closer you can get today.

Comment: @JoaquínO can you elaborate on this please ?

Comment: Did you figure out how to achieve this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind is uploading a photo to your server via AJAX, returning the link to the uploaded photo and then sending a message with the link to your photo using the method you described in your question. This is not *quite* the same as sending an image directly using Whatsapp since the recipient would only receive a link, but I doubt there will ever be a way to send an image to another application from your gallery using a webpage since that would raise some serious concerns.

Roughly, the process would like this (keep in mind that this will require some testing to get right and find a solution that works well on all platforms or at least most of them):

1. Create an image upload on your website. Simply having `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` on your page should, on most platforms, allow you to create a button which will open a dialog to select an image from your phone's gallery when clicked. You can find a [full example here](http://code.hootsuite.com/html5/) or use a library such as [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which contains many upload methods, including HTML5 which is what you need.
2. Create a simple server-side upload. This depends on your language and platform, but all you need to do is store the image somewhere and return a link to it in response. If you don't want to store these images on your server, you could forward it to [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image) and upload there.
3. Redirect the user to the `whatsapp://` link that contains the image link.

   ```
   window.location = 'whatsapp://send?text='+encodeURIComponent(imageURL);
   ```

   This is the point where you need to do some testing on different platforms, though. You might not be able to redirect to a `whatsapp://` link this way (since it seems like a security concern), so you may need to trick it (this is a bad idea, but I'm including it for the sake of completeness; the `data-action` part is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android)):

   ```
   var fakeLink = document.createElement('a');
   fakeLink.setAttribute('href', 'whatsapp://send?text='+encodeURIComponent(imageURL));
   fakeLink.setAttribute('data-action', 'share/whatsapp/share');
   fakeLink.click();
   ```

   In the end, if neither of these work, your best bet is creating a link once the upload is complete for the user to "confirm" sending which actually contains the above `whatsapp://` link in the `href` field.

There are many factors to test and some that are implementation specific so I had to keep it vague without much code - if you come across anything else when implementing this, please mention it in the comments.

Comment: Just reviewed this question. As of now I couldn't figure out a way to directly share an image on whatsapp so link sharing may be the easiest alternative from an website perspective. From an app there may be alternative ways though.

Comment: any solution on this?