# Sharrre and Whatsapp

Tags: jquery, whatsapp

Trying to use "whatsapp" share button along side with Sharrre (http://sharrre.com/).

So far The main idea is this:

**[see example](http://codepen.io/DreamsEngineering/pen/VYmvPX)**
*Please try it on your mobile if you want , of course.*

```
function shareme(shareElementMobile){
$(shareElementMobile).each(function (i) {
    var lnk = $(this).attr('data-url'),
        txt = $(this).attr('data-text'),
        resTxt = encodeURIComponent(txt),
        resLnk = encodeURIComponent(lnk);


    $(this).sharrre({
        share: {
            facebook: true,
            twitter: true,
            linkedin: true
        },
        template: '<ul class="box"><li><h2>{total}  <small>Compartido</small></h2></li><li id="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li><li id="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li><li id="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li><li id="whatsapp"><a href="whatsapp://send?text=' + resTxt + ' ' + resLnk + '"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li></ul>',
        enableHover: false,
        enableTracking: true,
        buttons: {
            facebook: {
                layout: 'button',
                send: true
            },
            twitter: {}
        },
        render: function (api, options) {

            $(api.element).on('click', '#twitter', function () {
                api.openPopup('twitter');
                return false;
            });

            $(api.element).on('click', '#facebook', function () {
                api.openPopup('facebook');
                return false;
            });

            $(api.element).on('click', '#linkedin', function () {
                api.openPopup('linkedin');
                return false;
            });

        }
    });


});
}

shareme('#sharemeMobile');
```

What happen is that the button of whatsapp doesn't' work at all.

Do I need to separate every social button??

Comment: `whatsapp://` is not a valid protocol, how do you intend to `href` to it?

Comment: @Shahar Software you install can register new protocol handlers with a browser. Those browsers *will* understand new URI types. Skype does the same.

Comment: Mörre is right , @Shahar , this is your the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out

I needed to add:

```
$(api.element).on('click', '#whatsapp', function () {
                api.openPopup('whatsapp');
                return false;
            });
```

and now everything is working properly .

Comment: is there any way to share or not ?what i meant is ,do something after  sucess sharing -Locke