# WhatsApp share button on a website - is it possible to share an image?

Tags: browser, whatsapp

Is it possible to share an image via WhatsApp through the web Browser? All I found was this: [Sharing link on WhatsApp from mobile website (not application) for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android) to share text. Is there any way to do this to trigger an image send via WhatsApp from the Web Browser?

Thanks in advance!