# How to share link via hike html (anchor tag href)

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I need html code to share my web page content through "Hike messenger" such as my page url, title and image.
As like we do have whatsapp share url code in [whatsapp share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android) -> '

Comment: Can you please elaborate, What you need exactly ?

Comment: may be it doesnt have short share option protocol support o_O