# Custom Whatsapp URL Scheme Code in mail

Tags: html, email, html-email, whatsapp, url-scheme

is there a way to open in gmail? if i send this in an email:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=wow%20check%20this%20out!%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeemanshop.com%2Fassortiment%2Fheren">deel dit bericht via Whatsapp!</a>
```

> deel dit bericht via Whatsapp!

If i send this to iphone mail it works, but gmail doesn't recognise this kind of custom scheme url. Is there a way to get this working without a safari/chrome redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the 'intent' required from Android, see this similar post for more info on it - [Sharing link on WhatsApp from mobile website (not application) for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android)

try replacing your above link with:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=wow%20check%20this%20out!%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeemanshop.com%2Fassortiment%2Fheren" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">deel dit bericht via Whatsapp!</a>
```

Hopefully adding the 'data-action' property will solve the issue. I get the feeling that at least some of the email clients will not be able to use the link correctly due to the varied support across client though.

Comment: thanks for the link! i was trying this with a gmail and it doesn't make a link out of this link cause its an invalid link. was more trying to get a answer to that problem.

Comment: at that point, it may be safer to just send them to a landing page link in the email that 'redirects' or POSTs the above link via JS or something once they load it as I have seen reference that it works across almost all mobile and desktop web browsers. (albeit, this is not exactly best practice)