# How can share product name and image on whatapps using html?

Tags: whatsapp

I'm trying to create script which can share product link and name. I searched about it and found an good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android).

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Above link is just sending product URL to whatapps, but i want to send title as well. Is there possible that i can send product title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to more searched about it and finally i got solution for this. I just add php syntax [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo urlencode ('http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=110'); ?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```