# Whatsapp share button for mobile friendly blogspot template

Tags: blogger, whatsapp, blogspot, socialshare

I am making a mobile friendly responsive Blogspot blogger template, with social media sharing buttons including WhatsApp, the button on template works fine when it comes to sharing URL of the post or blog, but I want it to sent text of the post instead of URL, if anyone can help me with codes, following is the codes for the WhatsApp button.

```
<a class='bitz' expr:data-href='data:post.url' expr:data-text='data:post.title' href='#' title='Share on whatsapp'><i class='fa fa-whatsapp'/></a>
```

Comment: Maybe you find some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android).

Comment: @web_xaser Code in my question works, it shows whatsapp icon under every post, and after some modifications like instead of "expr:data-href='data:post.url" i have added "expr:data-href='data:post.body" and because of this it actually share content of the post instead of just url of the post, but along with post the button share some codes as well like <p dir="ltr">, so if you can help me with it that'll be great.

Comment: Try to use "data:post.snippet" or "data:post.title".

Comment: @web_xaser "data:post.snippet" worked. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `data:post.snippet` to get a summary of the blog.