# how can i send url to specific contact through whatsapp from mobile web

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a web site, I need to send web URL to specific contact from WhatsApp.
I tried this code:

```
  <a href="whatsapp://send?text=https://www.example.com" >send </a>
```

In this code display contact list in WhatsApp. I need to send URL direct to specific contact.

Comment: Refer this question and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android

Comment: Nop you can not share to specific contact, but you will have to select contact to whom you're interested in sending.