# Sharing a url on whatsapp web

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

I want to share a url on https://web.whatsapp.com/. I have searched but I just share on mobile application. I used this code but doesnt open on whatsapp web. How can I do?

```
var message='https://example.com';
var url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
window.location.href=url;
```

Comment: Show what have you tried?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing link on WhatsApp from mobile website (not application) for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android)

Comment: I tried. Doesnt work!.