# Whatsapp share link does not work in safari

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796908/3437433

It works like a charm, but when I'm trying to use it in Safari (both desktop and mobile), then quite strange things happen.

On desktop, origin link `https://wa.me/?text=123` is somehow replaced with `whatsapp://send?text=123`. And then Safari displays error page about wrong protocol.

On mobile, correct page is opened by origin link, but also alert appears saying "can't open page because url is wrong". I can close that alert, can click on "send" button, but then `https://whatsapp.com/download/` page is opened, instead of prompting to login to whatsapp and redirecting to chat.

Does anybody know what's going on here and whether it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

We usually differ link at desktop view and mobile view to offer support for safari and other browser.
for desktop view we use
    https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=6200000000&text=Hello%20Moxqitto

for mobile, we follow whatsapp best practice https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/
    https://wa.me/6200000000

Tested on 
Chrome for mac
safari for mac
android chrome

Ps: not tested when mac have whatsapp desktop app, but it will still work in the safari itself. so it should be ok

Comment: are you aware of an api that checks if a phone number is connected with whatsapp?

Comment: as far as I know, it is currently only available for whatsapp business api which is still for select-invite only . You can request for the access at https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api

Answer (score 2):

[Official Sharing Documentation For WhatsApp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/).  They say to use their `wa.me/...` URL.  Okay!  So let's try it out!  http://wa.me/?text=mytest  For me, I get an error message...

> PAGE NOT FOUND

However, these seem to work great for me!

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]