# Vuejs vuetify link share via what's app, viber

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hi I created normal web app (Not a PWA) in vuetify. Most of times this web app is use in the mobile phones. So I want a button called **"share on what's app"** what does this button should do is open the what's app mobile app in the user's phone and let them to share on a chat. Is this possible with the vuetify? I mean I need `v-btn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
<v-btn>
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
</v-btn>
```

All I did was look for the url tag that's necessary for opening whatsapp from a web app and put it inside an a-href tag inside `v-btn`. I found help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796908/8459125).

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-btn>
  <a href="https://www.whatsapp.com/">Share via whatsapp</a>
</v-btn>
```

Use this to directly link to whatsapp website, and there it will ask you to open in app.
An easy hack.